# Problem with installing Pantheon shell on Ubuntu

Tags: shell, pantheon

Apologies beforehand if this is the wrong part of stackexchange to be asking this.

I get an error with installing Pantheon shell on Ubuntu Mini Remix. It says the following after installing Pantheon shell: update-gconf-defaults not found.

I'm not sure how to fix this. If more information is needed, I will need instructions on how to get it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package Pantheon is looking for in that error message is called `gconf-defaults-service`.

That being said, Pantheon is **not supported** for Ubuntu nor is there anyone maintaining a working version of it for Ubuntu (unlike Arch Linux). If you simply added an elementary OS PPA to your Ubuntu install, it won't work (or at least not in a sane way). The PPA is *not* working for Ubuntu as elementary OS ships additional patches in a separate PPA and Pantheon depends on packages from this repository. Nor will anyone fix Ubuntu-specific issues you might encounter.